# Using Spring Validator on Web services

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

Is it possible to use Spring Validators to validate data from Web Services Soap requests?  Or more so what should I change about the below approach to make it possible?

The precise context that I have is below:

I have a web front end using Freemarker and Controllers that works fine with validation for example using

```
<bean id="stockValidator" class="com.client.validator.StockValidator" />
```

In the dispatcher-servlet.xml

Then in the StockController the validation occurs on Post requests.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/addStock", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute Stock stock,BindingResult result,
   ModelMap model ) {

       StockValidator.validate(stock, result );
       if (result.hasErrors()) {
            //model.addAttribute("stock", stock);
            return "stock";
        } else {
            StockService.save(stock);
            model.addAttribute("stockId", stock.getStockId());
            model.addAttribute("stockCode", stock.getStockCode());
            model.addAttribute("stockName", stock.getStockName());

           return "result";
        }
   }
```

However my SOAP web services are Annotation based wired into the services

```
import javax.jws.WebService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.olympus.viewtheworld.server.dao.StockDao;
import com.olympus.viewtheworld.server.service.StockService;
import com.olympus.viewtheworld.shared.domain.Stock;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.server.service.StockService")
public class StockServiceImpl implements StockService{

@Autowired
StockDao stockDao;
```

This is mapped in the dispatcher servlet as such:

```
    <jaxws:endpoint id="stockService"
        implementorClass="com.server.service.Impl.StockServiceImpl"
        implementor="#stockServiceImpl"
        address="/SoapService/stock">
    <jaxws:serviceFactory>
        <ref bean="jaxws-and-aegis-service-factory"/>
    </jaxws:serviceFactory>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

Sorry I am a hobby developer and think that somewhere along the way I have got a bit confused in how best to approach this setup.  If it is more appropriate to start again from scratch let me know.

Cheers,
Rob

Answer (score 5):

You might want to look into Spring Web Services (http://projects.spring.io/spring-ws/). With that you can use [PayloadValidatingInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/soap/server/endpoint/interceptor/PayloadValidatingInterceptor.html) to run XSD-based validation on incoming SOAP messages.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just adding example of how to use @Jukka's suggested PayloadValidatingInterceptor.

You can PayloadValidatingInterceptor to intercept requests and validate it with XSD schema. E.g. (applicationContext.xml):

```
<sws:interceptors>
        <!-- Add our validating interceptor -->
        <ref bean="validatingInterceptor" />
    </sws:interceptors>
<bean id="validatingInterceptor" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor">
        <property name="schema" value="classpath:org/example/myproject/xsd/myprojectws.xsd"/>
        <property name="validateRequest" value="true"/>
        <property name="validateResponse" value="true"/>
    </bean>
```